# Logistic regression with categorical predictors using JAGS

Tags: model, logistic-regression, jags, runjags

I'm new to JAGS and I'm trying to predict a binary outcome (0/1) using 9 non-continuous predictors. Predictor values may be 0, 1 or 2. This is my first time doing this, and even though I can get the model to run, I am 100% sure there's definitely a number of issues here.

## Data file sample (list)

```
$y
[1] 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
[29] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0

$N
[1] 50

$oAnt
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
[29] 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1

$nAnt
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
[29] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

$cAnt
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
[29] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0

$oPen
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
[29] 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 2 1 1

$nPen
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1
[29] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1

$cPen
[1] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
[29] 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0

$oFin
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
[29] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

$nFin
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1
[29] 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3

$cFin
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
[29] 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
```

## Model

```
model {
    for( i in 1 : N ){
        y[i] ~ dbern(mu[i])
        mu[i] <- 1/(1+exp(-(b0 + b1*oAnt[i] + b2*nAnt[i] + b3*cAnt[i] + b4*oPen[i] + b5*nPen[i] + b6*cPen[i] + b7*oFin[i] + b8*nFin[i] + b9*cFin[i])))
}
b0 ~ dnorm(0, 1.0e-12)
b1 ~ dnorm(0, 1.0e-12)
b2 ~ dnorm(0, 1.0e-12)
b3 ~ dnorm(0, 1.0e-12)
b4 ~ dnorm(0, 1.0e-12)
b5 ~ dnorm(0, 1.0e-12)
b6 ~ dnorm(0, 1.0e-12)
b7 ~ dnorm(0, 1.0e-12)
b8 ~ dnorm(0, 1.0e-12)
b9 ~ dnorm(0, 1.0e-12)
}
```

I used estimates from a `glm()` model as inits (as suggest by A. Gelman)—but for the sake of simplicity, let's just assume I'll let JAGS pick the initial values for the chains.

## Running model etc.

```
jagsModel = jags.model(file = "antPenFin.txt", data = dataList, n.chains = 2, n.adapt = 500)

update(jagsModel, n.iter = 500)

codaSamples = coda.samples(jagsModel,
variable.names = names(dataList)[3:11], n.iter = 5000)
```

## Problems

The output of my model looks totally off (which becomes clear when I try to plot it). I'm sure there's some very basic issue here. Could somebody help out?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do each of the predictors mean and what are the three values associated to them?

Comment: The values range from 0 to 3, and in some cases they're binary (0/1). All the predictors are categorical, so there's nothing continuous here. Their meaning is: is a constituent present and, if yes, how many (values above).

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here is that you cannot supply a range of numbers (from 0 to 3 in your case) as categorical covariates.  Currently, your model is interpreting those numbers as continuous.  What you need to do is convert these to [dummy variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_variable_(statistics)).  You can do this easily using the `model.matrix` function in R.  I'm going to generate some data as an example, which you could then apply to your data.

```
# generate y
y <- sample(0:1, 30, replace = TRUE)
# add three different categorical covariates. Note here that these are all
# factors.
oAnt <- factor(sample(0:2, 30, replace = TRUE))
cAnt <- factor(sample(0:1, 30, replace = TRUE))
nFin <- factor(sample(0:3, 30, replace = TRUE))

# create your model matrix
my_matrix <- model.matrix(y ~ oAnt + cAnt + nFin)

head(my_matrix)

   (Intercept) oAnt1 oAnt2 cAnt1 nFin1 nFin2 nFin3
1           1     1     0     1     0     1     0
2           1     1     0     1     1     0     0
3           1     1     0     0     0     0     1
4           1     1     0     1     0     0     1
5           1     0     0     1     0     1     0
6           1     1     0     1     0     0     1
```

For each level in a factor for a predictor, you are going to need to create n-1 columns (e.g. nFin ranges from 0-3, you will create 3 columns of dummy variables).  Thus, you are going to have many more regresison coefficients to include in your model.  Once you make your model matrix you can convert it to a list as such.

```
# remove the intercept from the list as you already have it in your model
matrix_list <- as.list(data.frame(my_matrix[,-1]))
```

From there, all you need to do is create some more predictors for model. Also, if `nAnt` in your model is truly all ones, go ahead and remove that as well as you are basically just including two intercepts.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I still get a weird output (even after dummy coding the variables). For one thing, once I transform my coda samples output using the `ggs()` function, the variables come with indices. So, for example, `oAnt2[50]` for the last row in the data. More importantly, the values are all zeroes or ones, and I don't understand why.

Comment: Also: I've tried this whole thing using `MCMCglmm` and that worked out quite well—but I'd like to actually understand all the steps since I'm new to MCMC.

Comment: Are you tracking `OAnt2` in the model or the regression coefficients (e.g. `b1`)?

Comment: Actually, I managed to run it without dummy coding the variables (and it worked, just like with `MCMCglmm`. Then I change the model slightly to have only one predictor (factor). I dummy coded it and got the following error: `Error in node y[1] Node inconsistent with parents`. I'm not sure how to interpret the error, given that I only change the number of predictors (to 1 predictor with 3 levels, so 3 predictors after dummy coding)—all else is equal.

Comment: Go ahead and google that error. There is a lot of documentation online on what it means, both on stackoverflow as well as the JAGS forum.